# Rendering is different from what I set

Tags: rendering, color, shadows, color-management

My layout is formed by the following elements: a metallic spiral tube, two orthogonal planes with the same color(wall and pavement) together with a camera and a sun. I also removed the shadow from the spiral.
Unfortunately the outcome of the rendering is completely different:

[image]

There are huge differences i.e. **(1)** I didn't choose this dark red/maroon background, **(2)** the wall and the pavement should be white but, surprisingly, the wall takes the color of the background and **(3)** the spiral tube gets a shadow.

For the sake of clarity these are the settings concerning the background:

[image]

In *image* on the middle panel, I selected "white" since I want a white background.

On top of that this is my layout:

[image]

What am I missing? Why do I get that red/maroon background?
Is there a way to fix the colors of both the background and the wall?

Comment: Could you perhaps share your .blend file or your lighting settings?

Comment: Some info about your world environment color would be helpful as well - there is no reason for the maroon color (by default - missing tor broken things are either black or pink - never a different color). Also, perhaps an image from your Render Preview tab (not material preview) would be helpful, as it might show more about what's different between the preview and the actual render.

Comment: How did you remove the shadow? What Image panel are you referring to? One should change the world settings in the World tab of the Properties editor, or in the Shader Nodes editor set to World, or possibly the pull-down in the 3D Viewport editor. What are your world nodes? I suspect that red is a darkened violet indicating a missing texture. The wall being in shadow is expected, because the sun is directly overhead, and it’s pointing straight up. Being a computer model, it’s perfectly flat and perfectly aligned to the sun, so there’s no way for light to hit it.

Comment: "The settings concerning the background" are not background settings, but compositing nodes - which can also "do something" with the background but not primarily. The first and most interesting settings for your background would be the _World Properties_ and the _Render Properties_ - in the latter you should have enabled _Film_ > _Transparent_ or otherwise the _Alpha Over_ node in the _Compositor_ is absolutely useless.